# Problem in wiping cache partition?

Tags: recovery-mode, partitions, cache

I'm a moto g first gen user on 5.0.2 and I want to clear my cache.
I've done it before on kitkat, and I've had no problem.

But now, I'm having a problem. After pressing the volume down and power button, I reached the list of options. Then I selected recovery. But after that, I get the moto symbol, then a black screen for 2-3 seconds, then the android logo with an exclamation mark saying "No command."

The next step is to press and hold the volume up button for 10-15 seconds and then while holding, to press and release power button. But nothing's happening. I get stuck over there. On other forums I've read what people have suggested but it's basically the same thing.

I tried this 6-7 times but not happening. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

try this if you haven't figured it out yet..

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/HRALDucgBq4

Wiping the System Cache Partition
Wiping the system cache partition will not delete any files or data but always remember to backup anything important on a regular basis, ie/ photographs, music or document files.

If your device is switched on, power it off.

.
.
You'll see an image of an Android robot with a red exclamation mark

While holding the Power button, tap and release the Volume Up button - a menu should appear. (Do not hold the Volume Up button down as this will reboot the device).
Use the volume buttons to scroll to "wipe cache partition" and press the Power button to select it.